# 2 orderby method does not work correctly on firebase firestore android

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I want to make this scenario. A java object (lets called Foo) have two fields.

- one is "long" for timestamp
- one is "int" for the like count

I want timestamps less than today and then order these rows by like.

Here it's my code...

```
CollectionReference collectionReference = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("object");

    collectionReference.whereLessThan("weddingDateTimeMillis", System.currentTimeMillis())
            .orderBy("weddingDateTimeMillis")
            .orderBy("like", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).get().
addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {

        @SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions")
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {

            //...

        }

    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

            //...
        }
    });
```

But the code does not work that I hope. "like orderBy" is ignored and the list comes just ordered by timestamps.

I have created index automatically by clicking the link in logcat.

What is wrong with these? I don't understand the logic.

**EDIT**

Java class, sample json and firebase web interface can be found above. No input data needed for the request. And the response data only ordered by "weddingDateTimeMillis". I don't want to write output data, because it will be too long.

Object.Java

```
public class Wedding  Serializable {


private String parseId;

private User bride;
private User groom;

private Long weddingDateTimeMillis;

private String weddingAddress;

private Double locationLatitude;
private Double locationLongitude;

private String mailAddress;

private int like;

//getters and setters
```

sample JSON for the object

```
{
      "bride":{
         "name":"Many",
         "userType":"BRIDE"
      },
      "groom":{
         "name":"Long",
         "userType":"GROOM"
      },
      "like":32,
      "parseId":"04FFTYQwZbCAAXAn2W60",
      "weddingDateTimeMillis":1500118792847
   }
```

If you want to see all the test data, you can look up here : 
http://ardakaplan.com/test_json.txt

a screenshot for web interface in firebase console
[image]

Comment: Could you edit the question to illustrate some actual data you're querying, and the expected output from your query?  It's especially important to understand the types of the fields you're working with.

Comment: Please add what Doug Stevenson asked for and please also provide a screenshot of your database.

Comment: @AlexMamo  i have updated my question